# How do you drop infs from dask dataframe/series?

Tags: dask

I have a dask Series from which I need to drop both infs and nans.  `.dropna()` only drops the nans.  In numpy/pandas, I would do something like `result = result[np.isfinite(result)]`.  What's the recommended equivalent in dask-land?  Indexing the dask object with a boolean array gives an error.  Is there some way to tell dask that `inf` or `-inf` should be considered null values, for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid using NumPy functions.  These will trigger computation and future dask.dataframe operations will be hesitant about using those results.

Instead, use the equivalent dask.array function.  Here is a minimal example.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
   ...: import pandas as pd
   ...: import dask.dataframe as dd
   ...: import dask.array as da
   ...: df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [0, 1, 2], 'y': [0, np.inf, 5]})
   ...: df
   ...: 
Out[1]: 
   x         y
0  0  0.000000
1  1       inf
2  2  5.000000

In [2]: ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)
   ...: ddf[~da.isinf(ddf.y)].compute()
   ...: 
Out[2]: 
   x    y
0  0  0.0
2  2  5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I just discovered that I can do the following:

```
import dask.array as da
result = result[da.isfinite(result)]
```

In general it looks like just using `da.` array operations is the missing piece I've been looking for.